# Type Mismatch (Error 13) in Excel using Excel Json Parser VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel

Getting Type Mismatch (Error 13)  while using Json PArser in Excel MAcro

Below are the code :

```
Sub getJsonValue()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim JsonTS As TextStream
    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Card_Link.json", ForReading)
    JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close
    Set Json = ParseJson(JsonText)
    Set JsonRows = Json("rows")
    i = 2
    For Each Item In Json
         Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("name")
        'Sheet5.Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("results")("name")
        'Sheet5.Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("results")("responsecode")
        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Getting error on this statement 
`Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("name")`

Can someone please help me to resolve this.

Thanks
RJ

Answer (score 1):

Without having any experience with ParseJson, try one of these:

`Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).value = item`

`Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).value = item(0)`

`Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).value = item.Name`

If still none of these works, try like this:

```
For Each item In Json
    Stop
     Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).value = item("name")
    'Sheet5.Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("results")("name")
    'Sheet5.Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("results")("responsecode")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

On the stop, select `item`, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and see what do you have in `item`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).value = item  - this statement is working but I want to get the subitem values. I tried item(0), item.Name and item(Name) but nothing is working. Can you please help me

Comment: @user8472243 - have you tried Shift + F9? What happened?

Comment: Sorry for late response. In "Item", I am getting correct value now but when I am going to get the next level value like item.name or item(name). Its showing error - 424 (Run time Error) says "Object Required" on this statement - Sheet5.Cells(i, 2).Value = Item.Name

Comment: @user8472243 - how about `item("name")` or `item("Name")`?